# Pin headers that fit perf board that taper to DIP/SIP leg width

Tags: pin-headers

I'm building some emulator boards to replace some vintage GALs and DRAMs that have failed.  I'm planning to build out my circuit on perf board with the discrete/new components mounted there, using sets of sort-of pin headers extending below the board to fit into the DIP sockets on the original board.

Question:  I'm having trouble locating (or even figuring out what to search for) for either very thin pin headers (less preferable) or typical pitch headers that have pins on one end but taper down to something that will not do damage to the original sockets.  Sort of chip legs on one end and pin headers on the other.  What are these called?

I know I've seen them on boards, so I know they exist, but I have no idea what to call them to find them at a supply house.

Comment: I think you're talking about spring-loaded pogo pins.

Comment: @DKNguyen No, not pogo pins. More like a DIP insertion header/socket header? As in [this](https://www.antenk.com/ic-sockets-and-adapters/56983758.html)?

Comment: Maybe browse Samtec's website.

Comment: @DKNguyen Or something like [this](https://protostack.com.au/shop/connectors/headers/40-pin-2-54mm-snappable-headers-swiss-machine-pin/).

Comment: @jonk Oh. Milli-Max makes those I think.

Comment: [Gold Plated 2.54mm Male 40 Pin Single Row Straight Round Pin Header](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Gold-Plated-2-54mm-Male-40-Pin-Single-Row-Straight-Round-Pin-Header-Strip-10-Pcs/132142697372)

Comment: @BruceAbbott those look quite good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase to search on is "DIP header". But I tried this myself and when I dug down, I found it surprisingly difficult to locate suitable products. Apparently, this is a niche product whose demand is fading in the past.

So, although we don't normally do product recommendations here, I'm going to offer the [Mill-Max 350 series](https://www.mill-max.com/search/keywords/350) of single-row headers. Their 0.018" DIA round pins are much easier on IC sockets than the usual 0.025" square pins are. I've used them  myself when stacking boards directly to each other, and you can get them at Digi-Key, among other places.

Comment: Yup, those are very close to what I've used in the past (and still have a bunch in a vacuum sealed pouch for use when I need some again, someday.) The round pins are a must.

Comment: Those are perfect!  Thank you so much