# Mezzanine board connector recommendation

Tags: pcb-design, connector

I plan to develop a mezzanine PCB intended to sit in place of two ICs in an existing circuit and replace their function.  Height is limited as the device is only 1U high in total.

One of the original ICs is a 28 pin 0.6" DIP 8kB SRAM, and the other is a 16 pin 0.3" DIP 74HC138 which acts as an address decoder.   My intent is to replace the 8kB RAM with a 32kB RAM and a GAL to act as an improved address decoder.

What would be the most appropriate connectors to use for the connection between the two boards ideally such that I can simply remove the board and re-insert the original ICs if desired?   The existing ICs are not currently socketed.  There's enough space available that I don't need to use the footprint of any such connectors to hold components.

Comment: I didn't even know you could still buy GALs! It will, however, be impossible to recommend connectors without even knowing what package your existing ICs have? Are they PLCC, LGA or PDIP? Also: what are the speed requirements?

Comment: (for other packages, socketing will be hard)

Comment: Please show a picture of the PCB, with annotations.

Comment: @MarcusMüller They're all DIP (sorry, thought that was implicit when I talked about 0.6" and 0.3" width packages)

Comment: @Fredled the new PCB?   It doesn't exist yet.   The two existing ICs are pictured at https://www.imgpaste.net/image/9wFma

Comment: @MarcusMüller speed is sub 2 MHz.  The GALs will be ATF16V8B most likely - still widely available.

Comment: hm, that sounds like you could just drop in a modern microcontroller (>=100 MHz!) to emulate both decoder and RAM)

Comment: @MarcusMüller that would be massive overkill - I only need an 80 cent GAL and a single RAM chip.   Using a microcontroller instead would at the very least need a bunch of passives, a xtal, firmware, and most likely the need to bidirectionally convert voltage levels too (the original system is 5V).

Comment: @Alnitak nope, a modern microcontroller comes with an on-chip oscillator, and typically needs one or two decoupling caps; so that's less components than your solution, at a lower cost. There's 5V capable MCUs for the automotive market, and 80ct isn't that cheap - and writing a MCU firmware sounds easier to me than designing the GAL configuration (but that's personal preference).

Comment: I wrote the GAL config last night - it took 10 minutes (and it was the first time I'd ever written one).   Also, the RAM needs to be non-volatile.

Comment: huh, your SRAM is non-volatile?

Comment: The SRAM is battery backed, powered from a battery that'll remain on the main PCB.     (not that any of this answers my original question about connectors... :p )

Comment: @Alnitak ah interesting! Yeah, but then you can have the same with a microcontroller.

Comment: I found another question that appears to solve this one - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465083/pin-headers-that-fit-perf-board-that-taper-to-dip-sip-leg-width

Comment: @Alnitak "to sit in place of two ICs in an existing circuit " Please show said existing circuit. To advise about a connector I need to go visual,

Comment: @MarcusMüller "and writing a MCU firmware sounds easier to me" except when you have to do it for the very first time. It's a thing worth learning if you embrace doing many projects of this kind, But the first time, you can loose days.

Comment: true, but the same happens with designing a multi-IC mezzanine board, it *could* have happened with programming the GAL, it can happen with anything.

Comment: @MarcusMüller FWIW I'm already familiar with PIC and AVR8, but performing RAM emulation would likely need a fast AVR32 or an ARM CPU (with at least 28 I/Os) in order to be able to reliably service the host CPU's *5 volt* bus in a timely fashion.   That not only means a new instruction set, but new tool chains and programming devices.  I really think what you're proposing is way over the top when all I need is a 16V8 SPLD with a few product terms in it to act as an address decoder and a $1 RAM chip.  The connectors will end up costing more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I found another [similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465083/pin-headers-that-fit-perf-board-that-taper-to-dip-sip-leg-width) which suggested looking for "DIP headers", which has led me to the CnC Tech 200 series of thru-hole M-M DIP adapters.

These have turned pins which will be suitable for plugging into IC sockets installed on the main PCB.

Comment: part link for reference - https://www.arrow.com/en/products/220-1-28-006/cnc-tech-llc

Comment: DIP header, strip header, etc.  Or, a wire-wrap socket on the mezz.  What is the total height above board you have to work with?  (1U minus pcb standoffs minus pcb thickness minus mounting frame / packaging minus clearance above the mezz board)

Comment: AND, what is the minimum RAM write-cycle time in your application?